# Is it possible to use the Stack Exchange engine internally?

Tags: support, so-engine

Is there a way to setup the Stack Exchange engine to run on an intranet for a corporation?

The idea being that users can go to the site, submit a question and have it routed appropriately by moderation.

This way non-technical users can go to the site, post up a question. And then IT can route the question to software, customer service, helpdesk, etc. Each division being its own specific site.

If possible, how feasible is it? Does it require a lot of setup/maintenance? Are there fees involved? Can it be re-skinned?